# HTML5 Change the url subdomain using replaceState

Tags: html, firefox, firebug

I have an app in a domain like this http://www.example.com/, but I need to replace the state to a subdomain, like this http://test.example.com/.

I'm trying to do this with replaceState like this:

`history.replaceState({}, '', 'http://test.example.com/')`

But in Firebug I'm getting an error:

`Error: Security error`

I understand this maybe is breaking **Same Origin Policy**. Is there a way to set the subdomain without reloading the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  You can't change the origin of the page without reloading it, precisely because it would violate the same-origin policy.

Comment: After a little more of research, I think I given up on this. Since I'm not changing the domain itself (only the subdomain) I thought this could be done. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Has anyone attempted doing this with a CORS policy in place? Hoping that if I setup CORS on my subdomain I might be able to switch to it.

Comment: CORS doesn't affect the behavior here.